# Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling startHeadlessTask)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, service

I've developed a React Native application that includes a background service operating continuously, managed by Work Manager. This service involves a HeadlessJsTask for tasks like tracking, which need to run for extended periods, especially while the user is driving. To indicate that the service is active, a silent foreground notification is displayed.

The Work Manager is responsible for monitoring whether the foreground service is active. If it's not, it restarts the HeadlessJs Service to continue detecting driving activity and perform necessary actions.

Initially, this setup functions correctly, even if the app is closed or the phone is restarted. However, after a variable period ranging from hours to days, an error begins to occur every time the Work Manager attempts to start the HeadlessJsTask, preventing its execution. The error messages are:

> "Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling startHeadlessTask)." This often suggests a mistake in the application entry file path.

> E ReactNativeJS: This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes

To set up the HeadlessTask, I use the following registration process:

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('LocationUpdate', () => MyHeadlessTask);
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Root);
```

This code operates correctly for a while, which leads me to wonder if the issue could be related to the operating system, such as battery optimization restrictions (I'm using a Realme phone with Android 13).

Given that the error only begins after an unpredictable duration, sometimes days, it's challenging to test or debug. I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you!